# Cómo cambiar el tamaño a Aplicacion UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación UWP en C#, todo va de maravilla con excepción que no puedo cambiar de tamaño a la "ventana" de la aplicación así como evitar el redimensionamiento, he buscado por todo sitio pero no hallo la solución que funcione.

> No pongo código porque no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vaya que por fin encontré un código que funciona para cambiar el tamaño, pero aún no he logrado dar con el que permitirá evitar el redimensionamiento.

Ahí les dejo el código:

```
//ancho, alto  
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(200, 400);
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(200, 400));
```